# Why my Background-image is not showing up on my github.io?

Tags: url, github, background-image

I've included 2 svg images for my background, one is at top and other at bottom. With my local host (live server) they show up without any problem, but now that is uploaded at github it doesn't show at all. I don't know what's wrong since all the assets (folder with images) are correctly uploaded.
Chrome shows this error:
2 GET https://ruth9403.github.io/assets/images/bg-top.svg 404`enter image description here`

I'm a noob just doing my first attemps of web pages :'v, and also new at github. 
This is my github repository:
https://github.com/ruth9403/pricing-toggle-hamburger.github.io

And this is my github url for the project:
https://ruth9403.github.io/pricing-toggle-hamburger.github.io/

Thanks a lot for your time, and your kind soul!:D[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZvVr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with your path. Your CSS file is in the folder assets. And your absolute CSS path after resolution points to `https://ruth9403.github.io/pricing-toggle-hamburger.github.io/assets/assets/images/bg-bottom.svg` which doubles the `assets` folder.

Hence you have to change the image path for the background to `images/bg-bottom.svg`. Basically you have an issue with your relative path. For CSS files always the folder where the CSS file is located is used as "starting point" for the traversal.

Should solve it:

```
body {
    background: url("images/bg-bottom.svg"), url("images/bg-top.svg");
}
```

at least it did for me :P.

Comment: Thank you so much!, it was really that!! :D

Comment: @RuthJimenez You're welcome! I was quite certain about that :P.

Answer (score 1):

A project site is  available at `http(s)://<user>.github.io/<repository>`

In your case: https://github.com/ruth9403/pricing-toggle-hamburger (not `https://github.com/ruth9403/pricing-toggle-hamburger.github.io`)

Make sure to check the [settings of your repository](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site#creating-your-site) in order to activate the page publication.
Make sure the [publishing source is `master`](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#publishing-sources-for-github-pages-sites) (it would be the `gh-pages` branch otherwise by default for a project page).

Comment: This is a good general point for gh pages but I don't think this is the issue for the background not displaying. It has to do with the relative path used.

Comment: @thex Before that, it has issue with the URL itself